# overlay with same height as overflow content

Tags: html, css

this is my fiddle which shows my problematic.
I would like to realize, that the overlay div has the same height than the content div.
You can see the problem if you scroll down. The overlay is as high as the box div.

For this case the content has fix height of 600px.
But in my live situation it has a dynamic height.

How can I solve this issue?

```css
#box {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content {
  height: 600px;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="overlay">[ OVERLAY ]</div>
  <div id="content">
    This is my Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not possible with this structure - there is no _relation_ between the two elements, so that the overlay _could_ get its height from the content element. You would need to put the overlay _into_ the content element, an position it in regard to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is a nice solution for your issue:

I moved the `div#overlay` to be inside the content, its absolute positioning can easily fit to the parent's size when the parent has the attribute `position: relative`.

I updated your snipped below:

```css
#box {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="overlay">[ OVERLAY ]</div>
    This is my Content
  </div>
</div>
```